# Applying a filter in ViewModel when value from the ViewModel change

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to bind twice data on my application.
I have two list view. The first one is the list of all element that are present with a checkbox.
The second list view have to get only the Value where the checkbox is checked.

So I tried to deal with a ViewMode and two ObservableCollection. One full and one that will be filtered. But I dont get it to work. Is it the good way to do it ?

thank you!

Here is the XAML code :

```
<!-- The full collection -->
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Cycles.MyData}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource SwitchOnly}" IsChecked="{Binding Cycles.Used, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
<!-- The filtered collection -->
<ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Cycles.MyDataFiltered}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn>
                 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource VisualOnly}" IsChecked="{Binding Check}"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn>
             <GridViewColumn>
                 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn>
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

Here is the ViewModel :

```
public class ViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Cycles> MyData { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Cycles> MyDataFiltered { get; set; }

    private bool _used = true;
    public bool Used
    {
        get => _used;
        set
        {
            _used = value;
            _myDataView.Filter = Filter;
            OnPropertyChanged("Used");
        }
    }

    private Cycles _currentSelectedCycle;
    public Cycles CurrentSelectedFamily
    {
        get => _currentSelectedCycle;
        private set
        {
            _currentSelectedCycle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSelectedFamily");
        }
    }


    readonly ICollectionView _myDataView;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyData = new ObservableCollection<Cycles>();
        MyDataFiltered = new ObservableCollection<Cycles>();
        _myDataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyDataFiltered);
        _myDataView.CurrentChanged += delegate
        {
            CurrentSelectedFamily = (Cycles)_myDataView.CurrentItem;
        };
    }
    private static bool Filter(object item)
    {
        var value = (Cycles)item;
        return value != null && value.Check;
    }
}
```

Here is my Cycle class :

```
public class Cycles : PropertyChangedBase
{
    internal Cycles()
    {
        _check = false;
        _firstDay = 1;
    }

    private bool _check;
    private string _name;
    private int _firstDay;
    private int _lastDay;

    public bool Check
    {
        get => _check;
        set
        {
            if (_check == value) return;
            _check = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Check");
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (_name == value) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public int FirstDay
    {
        get => _firstDay;
        set
        {
            if (_firstDay == value) return;
            _firstDay = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstDay")
        }
    }
    public int LastDay
    {
        get => _lastDay;
        set
        {
            if (_lastDay == value) return;
            _lastDay = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastDay");
        }
    }
}
public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your Cycles class.

Comment: drive.google.com/open?id=0B4bUNjAQRJpWMXpGSk1fRTVSeDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use below binding for your Second list**

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCycles}"
```

**and in view model**

```
public IEnumerable<Cycles> SelectedCycles
 {
  get { return MyData.Where(x => x.Check== true); }
 }
```

Comment: I tried your solution and the SelectedCycles is correctly updated when I called it but with the binding it don't update. What I have to add ?

Comment: Your Datacontext for your Xaml Window should be your ViewModel. And Binding should not have Cycles.  use direct for e.e SelectedCycles or MyData.

Comment: I was trying this while you answerd but still the same result, I don't have the element in the SelectedCycles :/ Is it the way I bind the checked Value ?.

Comment: Let me give you full example

Comment: what is Cycles is in ItemsSource="{Binding Cycles.MyDataFiltered}"> I believe you can improve binding

Comment: it was a second observable collection to store the checked value. But i wiped it with you solution which sounds better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152306/discussion-between-ramankingdom-and-thibaud).

Comment: thank you ! that's exactly what I was looking for ! I need to learn more about the MVVM process